# Reload in a specific container content does not work after updating jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a weird issues regarding a jquery update.
While I am including jquery 3.3.1 with

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the code below works like a charm and is reloading my .php in the targeted `<div>` container.

```html
<select name="vehicle" id="selvehicle" onchange="reloadIssues()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div class="text-left alert alert-warning h4" id="vissues">
    some content here
</div>

function reloadIssues() {
    var vehicle = document.getElementById('selvehicle').value;
    $('#vissues').load('carcheck.knownissues.php?vehicle=' + vehicle);
};
```

When I include jquery 3.5.1

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

as it is currently recommended on the Bootstrap website, the function reloadIssues() does not work anymore. There's nothing happening upon changing the options in the `select` tag.

Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong or how I can polish the script a bit ti get it running with the new jquery version?

PS: the rest of the site is working with both versions and without any other problems. I do actually not rely on the new version, I just prefer to have one up to date to be honest.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that it was the *.slim*-version on the bootstrap website which does not include the **ajax** functionalities.

I just replaced it with the normal *.min*-version and it works perfectly.